# How to implement Highcharts column-drilldown chart in Rails application?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts, lazy-high-charts

I'm trying to implement a Highcharts [Column-Drilldown Chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown) in my Rails application using [lazy_high_charts](https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts). I want to display data that's being pulled from my database and stored in four arrays (areas, areaScores, departments, and deptScores). I'm having trouble converting the JS from the [example (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-drilldown/) listed on the highchart site into ruby. I have not been able to find any resources on creating a column-drilldown chart in ruby. Any help on how to integrate the drilldown chart into my ruby application would be highly appreciated.

I have included the sample JavaScript shown on the Highcharts demo page and my controller method that populates the four arrays with data and builds the highchart.

**Highcharts Column-Drilldown Chart Example (Javascript)**

```
$(function () {

    Highcharts.data({
        csv: document.getElementById('tsv').innerHTML,
        itemDelimiter: '\t',
        parsed: function (columns) {

            var brands = {},
                brandsData = [],
                versions = {},
                drilldownSeries = [];

            // Parse percentage strings
            columns[1] = $.map(columns[1], function (value) {
                if (value.indexOf('%') === value.length - 1) {
                    value = parseFloat(value);
                }
                return value;
            });

            $.each(columns[0], function (i, name) {
                var brand,
                    version;

                if (i > 0) {

                    // Remove special edition notes
                    name = name.split(' -')[0];

                    // Split into brand and version
                    version = name.match(/([0-9]+[\.0-9x]*)/);
                    if (version) {
                        version = version[0];
                    }
                    brand = name.replace(version, '');

                    // Create the main data
                    if (!brands[brand]) {
                        brands[brand] = columns[1][i];
                    } else {
                        brands[brand] += columns[1][i];
                    }

                    // Create the version data
                    if (version !== null) {
                        if (!versions[brand]) {
                            versions[brand] = [];
                        }
                        versions[brand].push(['v' + version, columns[1][i]]);
                    }
                }

            });

            $.each(brands, function (name, y) {
                brandsData.push({ 
                    name: name, 
                    y: y,
                    drilldown: versions[name] ? name : null
                });
            });
            $.each(versions, function (key, value) {
                drilldownSeries.push({
                    name: key,
                    id: key,
                    data: value
                });
            });

            // Create the chart
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Browser market shares. November, 2013'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Source: netmarketshare.com.'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'category'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Total percent market share'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
                        }
                    }
                },

                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
                }, 

                series: [{
                    name: 'Brands',
                    colorByPoint: true,
                    data: brandsData
                }],
                drilldown: {
                    series: drilldownSeries
                }
            })

        }
    });
});
```

**My Controller:**

```
  def generateOrgBreakdownReport
    # First, query the database for the data you need for the report
    @jsonanswerBRKD = queryDatabaseForOrgProgressReport()

    # Second, process and combine data as needed for the report
    @areaBreakdown, @deptBreakdown, @employBreakdown = computeAreaAndDeptPrepareScore(@jsonanswerBRKD)

    # Third, you'll need to put the processed data into a format 
    # Highcharts will understand for the data series it uses
    # for the graph. 

    #THESE ARRAYS HOLD THE NAMES AND SCORES OF AREAS AND DEPARTMENTS
     @deptScores, @departments, @areaScores, @areas = cycleThroughProcessedDataAndCreateHighChartsDataSetsBreakdown(@areaBreakdown, @deptBreakdown, @employBreakdown) 

    # Last, we put the newly made data sets for Highcharts to work its magic.

    #DONT KNOW HOW TO IMPLEMENT DRILLDOWN FOR RUBY
    @orgBreakdown = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('column') do |f|
      f.chart( type: 'column' )
      f.xAxis(
        title: { text: "Areas" },
        type: 'category'
      )
      f.yAxis(
        title: { text: "Preparedness Score (%)"},
      )
      f.series(
        name: "Department Score",
        colorByPoint: true, 
        data: @deptScores
      )
      f.series(
        name: "Area Score", 
        data: @areaScores
      )
      f.title( 
        text: "Organizational Breakdown"
      )
      f.options[:xAxis][:categories] = @areas
      f.drilldown({:series=>{
        name:"Dept. Score",
        data: @deptScore
        }
        })

    end
  end
```

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: @MarkThomas How does one implement the drilldown features of Highcharts in a Ruby web application controller? I have started implementing the chart, but I can't find any resources strictly for ruby pertaining to the drilldown features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used Lazy Highcharts, but assuming it mirrors the JSON from the [JavaScript API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#drilldown) you need to add the sub-series by name, e.g.

```
  f.series(
    name: "Department Score",
    colorByPoint: true, 
    data: @deptScores,
    drilldown: "subdept"  #add this 
  )
```

Then you'll need to add drilldown data, and if Lazy Highcharts supports it, it might look something like this:

```
  f.drilldown(
    series: {
      id: "subdept",
      data: [
        ["One", 1],
        ["Two", 2],
        ["Three", 3]
      ]
    }
  )
```

See this [basic drilldown fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/basic/) to see how the resulting Javascript should look.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm still confused on how the chart is animated. Is the JavaScript in the fiddle responsible for animating the drilldown effect? Should this JavaScript be contained to the controller? Or will I have to include JavaScript in the view as well to get the desired effect?

Comment: Yes, Highcharts does all the animation for you. You just have to provide the JSON as shown. You may need to do this manually if Lazy doesn't support the drilldowns.

Answer (score 0):

To get drilldown to work in Rails you have to make sure you include the drilldown module in your JavaScript manifest file (application.js).

I also had to download the file as it was not my highcharts module catalogue. You can find the file here: http://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js

Add this to application.js:

```
//= require highcharts/modules/drilldown
```

Outside of Rails you can include the drilldown module like this:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
```